# WiX Bootstrapper run executable on exit

Tags: windows, wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I'm using the WiX (3.6) Burn bootstrapper to bundle a prerequisite component (Bonjour) with the setup for my program.  It works great and all, but:

I'd like to add a step to the end where I run an executable from my INSTALLDIR on exit.  I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring this out.

I've tried:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp"  Directory="INSTALLDIR"
              ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]my app name.exe"/>
```

But don't know where to put it in my Burn's bundle wxs file.  Any pointers?  Thanks!

Edit:

I've also tried putting the following:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp"  Directory="INSTALLDIR"
              ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]Any Send.exe"/>
```

at the end of my app's installer MSI, but when it gets integrated into the Burn bootstrapper install, this line doesn't appear to be executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

Add the following to your  element (I added it right after `BootstrapApplicationRef` and before `Chain`):

```
 <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" 
           Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder]Folder\Exe Name.exe"/>
```

Totally did the trick for me!